# ColdFusion: cfspreadsheet localized date format

Tags: excel, date, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

My question is basically the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926719/coldfusion-cfspreadsheet-reading-date-incorrectly), but I'm not in a position to change the date format in the Excel file:

> If I format the cell as date english (NZ), ie  Date Type "*14/03/2001", it displays
>   right in the spreadsheet, but when I try to upload it switched the day
>   and month. But If I change the format to a custom "dd/mm/yyyy" format
>   [it works fine].

So the question is this: Can I change the way <cfspreadsheet /> handles date formats? Or even better, get a Date object directly from the Excel import.

EDIT:

I found a solution by using POI:

```
<cfset fileIS = createObject( "java", "java.io.FileInputStream" ).init( "#request.site.sImportPath#\#variables.file#" ) />
<cfset excelFS = createObject( "java", "org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem" ).init( fileIS ) />
<cfset workBook = CreateObject( "java", "org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook" ).init( excelFS ) />
<cfset sheet = workBook.getSheet( "mySheetName" ) />

<cfset myDateValue = sheet.getRow( 20 ).getCell( 2 ).getDateCellValue() />
```

When using `getDateCellValue()` you get the actual date as a usable ColdFusion date back. It would've been nice if `<cfspreadsheet />` did this natively.

Comment: What did you set with `SetLocale()`?

Comment: I tried both en_US and nl_NL, no change.

Comment: If you are receiving a predictable format, you can use ParseDateTime to cast it to a date object.

Comment: I can't really rely on the format the date was entered in, some actually are properly date formatted, some use the asterisk method. I already had a function in place that tried to figure out in what format the date was entered, but in the end there's always the 5/4/2013 date that's not going to be predictable.

Comment: If I were in the situation where something was ambiguous, I would ask the person for whom I was doing the job to decide what to do about it.

Comment: I am not positive, but I do not think you can change the way regional formats are handled without changing the locale at the jvm or o/s level. *RE: Or even better, get a Date object directly from the Excel import.* You can, but not with CFSpreadsheet or any of the built-in functions. You have to [do it yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028511/reading-column-format-with-cfspreadsheet/9030012#9030012).

Comment: Thanks Leigh, I ended up doing exactly that (see my edit.)

Comment: Yes, it would be nice if CF exposed more of this type of functionality.  That above looks good. Just keep in mind the rows/cells/values might be `null`. Could you post that as an "answer", so it is more visible? (Answering your own question is allowed :).

Comment: BTW, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Good first question :)

Comment: After YEARS of lurking finally decided to start asking and answering questions here. Thanks for your help, I've added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution by using POI:

```
<cfset fileIS = createObject( "java", "java.io.FileInputStream" ).init( "#request.site.sImportPath#\#variables.file#" ) />
<cfset excelFS = createObject( "java", "org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem" ).init( fileIS ) />
<cfset workBook = CreateObject( "java", "org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook" ).init( excelFS ) />
<cfset sheet = workBook.getSheet( "mySheetName" ) />

<cfset myDateValue = sheet.getRow( 20 ).getCell( 2 ).getDateCellValue() />
```

When using getDateCellValue() you get the actual date as a usable ColdFusion date back. It would've been nice if  did this natively.